# pressing ctrl+w in mysql workbench results in ETB

Tags: mysql, sql, user-interface, ide, mysql-workbench

So I'm using the MySQL Workbench SQL Editor 5.2.45 CE

However whenever I try to close a tab using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, instead of closing the tab it prints out "ETB" in the query editor instead and does not close the tab...

Any idea what's causing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably working on Windows. The ETB output is from the editor when the hotkey is not handled in the UI and hits the editors input processor without being defined for an action (like select word or copy to clipboard). The editor control is a Scintilla instance which is able to also display non-printable characters.

The hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> was previously used to close tabs, but since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is much more common on Windows it was changed. So use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in the future instead.